# Correct way to make a non-question post if possible

Tags: discussion

I worked on a [document](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62856/23058) which did not ask a specific question but was related to 3.x and Pathfinder, it was a collection of useful articles are various topics, usually related to classes. It was deleted (then put on hold) because it either wasn't clear enough or was not specifically asking for a question. When I joined the site I thought I saw an post which was a document about [creating undead and it being an evil act](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41664/23058) and it turns out that what I remembered was actually an answer and not the original post.

So would the correct way to go about creating a collection of useful material for users be to ask it as a question and then provide my own solution, or is this just something I should not be doing?

Answer (score 10):

We're a site which answers questions. If you have useful material to blog about, you should start a blog. The research you're doing is valuable, just... not here.

There are questions looking for documentation like: [Are the WotC archives of d20 Character Optimization forum forever lost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/are-the-wotc-archives-of-d20-character-optimization-forum-forever-lost/9050#9050)

But every question must pose a specific problem that can have a singular, best, answer. The best sort of resource there is a forum. We've tried to maintain a glossary in the past and... it didn't age well.

My recommendation is, if you're going to start a competitor to the handbook indexes, compile it in google docs, share it, and then use it as a linked resource to questions that pose a problem it can answer.

Comment: Ah, it had not been my intent on trying to compete with handbook indexes. The aging issue is also something that I had not considered. Since Im not currently a member of any forms, I should save my results for myself (and maybe players) and close the post.

Comment: Well, preserving it in a google doc and sharing it is fine, but if you're not trying to compete then it's just a local index for you. If it's useful *when* you're answering, link naturally.

Comment: So, would the best course of action be to delete it, vote to close it, ...?

Comment: If it cannot be improved to be a question, I would urge self-deletion. Otherwise it'll just hang around and collect downvotes.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the assistance on this